# R Shiny: Use reactiveValues() with data.table assign-by-reference

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I have a shiny app in which more than one reactive component uses the same result from a function that is slow to calculate.  To avoid calculating the slow function more than once, I can use `reactiveValues()` to recalculate the function when its inputs change, and make the result available to all reactive components that require it.

But, if the `reactiveValues` object is a `data.table`, and I update it using `:=`, shiny does not detect the change, and the outputs that rely on it do not get updated.

Is there any way to use data.table assign by reference either with `reactiveValues` or another way that avoids recalculating the function multiple times.

Here is a reproducible example using data.table assign-by-reference in which `output$result2` fails to get updated when the input changes:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput('x1', 'x1', min=0, max=2, value=1, step=0.1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('result1'),
      verbatimTextOutput('result2')
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$dt = data.table(v1 = 1:100, v2 = 1)

  slow.func = function(my.dt, x) {
    Sys.sleep(2)
    my.dt[, v2 := v1^x]
  }

  output$result1 = renderPlotly({
    values$dt = slow.func(values$dt, input$x1)
    plot_ly(values$dt) %>%
      add_lines(x = ~v1, y = ~v2)
  })      
  output$result2 = renderText({
    paste('Final value =', values$dt[.N, v2])
  })  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For comparison, here is a version of the server function using standard assignment of data.frames, which does perform as expected:

```
server = function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$dt = data.frame(v1 = 1:100, v2 = 1)

  slow.func = function(my.dt, x) {
    my.dt$v2 = my.dt$v1^x
    Sys.sleep(2)
    my.dt
  }

  output$result1 = renderPlotly({
    values$dt = slow.func(values$dt, input$x1)
    plot_ly(values$dt) %>%
      add_lines(x = ~v1, y = ~v2)
  })

  output$result2 = renderText({
    paste('Final value =', values$dt[100,]$v2)
  })  
}
```

Comment: How about just having a reactive value 'table_updated' as a flag and increment it by one each time you want all other values to be notified. These values will only need to observe 'table_updated'

Comment: @KeqiangLi Thanks - that definitely sounds like one possible approach. Feel free to post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: sure, added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

say you have defined a reactive variable `table_updated` so you can increment it by one each time the slow function is done. Other values/plots will only need to observe `table_updated`.

Actually the [actionButton(see description section)](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/actionButton.html) does the same thing, every time it gets clicked, its value is incremented by 1.

```
values <- reactiveValues(table_updated = 0)

slow.func = function(my.dt, x) {
  # do stuff
  values$table_updated <- values$table_updated + 1
}

output$result2 = renderText({
  values$table_updated
  paste('Final value =', values$dt[100,]$v2)
})
```